# onchange event not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

in this piece of code i have 2 dropdown lists. one is department and the other is section name. on the basis of department i am changing my section name accordingly and then pushing these two dropdown list's values into my form's input.

The problem is that onchange event is working fine in chrome but not in firefox if you use keyboard(tab key and arrow keys) only. how can i fix this without adding jquery??

```js
function fields(){
     var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");//seldprt is for Department
     var section = seldprt.value;//assigning the value of Department dropdown list to section variable
     var dprt_input=section;
     var input_Department=document.getElementById("departmentinput");
     input_Department.value=dprt_input;
      if(section=="REGULATORY")
      {
        
        document.getElementById("LEGALDiv").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("REGDiv").style.display="";
        var subsection=document.getElementById("REGDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input=subsection.value;      
        var input_Subcatagory=document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;
      } 
      else if(section=="LEGAL")
      {
      
        document.getElementById("LEGALDiv").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("REGDiv").style.display="none";
        var subsection=document.getElementById("LEGALDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input=subsection.value;      
        var input_Subcatagory=document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;
      } 
      }
```

```html
<div  class="departmentdiv" onclick="fields()"><!-- here the function field is called on onclick event -->
      <label>Department Name:</label> 
      <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
      <select id = "seldprt" onfocus="fields();" onchange="fields();" onkeypress="fields();">
       <option value = "LEGAL">LEGAL</option>
       <option value = "REGULATORY">REGULATORY</option>
      </select>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div id="REGDiv" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none" >
      <label>Section Name:</label>
       <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
        <select id = "REGDiv_subcatagory" onfocus="fields()" onchange="fields()" onkeypress="fields()">
         <option value = "GLT">GLT</option>
         <option value = "REGULATORY">REGULATORY</option>
        </select>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div id="LEGALDiv" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none" >
      <label>Section Name:</label>
       <div align="right" class="selectdiv" >
        <select id = "LEGALDiv_subcatagory" onfocus="fields()" onchange="fields()" onkeypress="fields()">
         <option value = "GLT">GLT</option>
         <option value = "LEGAL">LEGAL</option>
        </select>
       </div>
     </div>

    <form action="" method="post" >
       <div class="entry" onclick="previous_values()" style="">Name</div>
       <input type="text" style="" name="name" id="departmentinput">
       <div class="entry" style="" onclick="previous_values()">Section Number</div>
       <input type="text" style="" name="Section" id="subcatagoryinput">
       <div id="readwrite_buttons" class="hide">
        <button id="ok" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">OK</button>
        <button id="cancel" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Cancel</button>
       </div>
       <div id="readonly_buttons" class="hide">
        <button id="back" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Back</button>
       </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: This snippet works as described in Firefox for me, updating the text inputs to match whatever is selected in the select box. Can you validate that the snippet is broken in Firefox for you?

Comment: it works fine if you are using mouse but when using keyboard(using tab and arrow keys) only it does not work in firefox.

Comment: Ah, in firefox onchange doesn't get fired until the box loses focus. That's their intended behaviour. See here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=296125

Comment: any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onkeyup event should do what you're trying to do. It's could potentially generate a lot of events, so I would consider carefully whether it's really necessary. I saw that you tried the onkeypress event in your snippet. For reasons unknown to me, at least in firefox, it doesn't seem to catch the up/down arrows while onkeyup and onkeydown apparently do.

```js
function fields(){
     var seldprt = document.getElementById("seldprt");//seldprt is for Department
     var section = seldprt.value;//assigning the value of Department dropdown list to section variable
     var dprt_input=section;
     var input_Department=document.getElementById("departmentinput");
     input_Department.value=dprt_input;
      if(section=="REGULATORY")
      {
        
        document.getElementById("LEGALDiv").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("REGDiv").style.display="";
        var subsection=document.getElementById("REGDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input=subsection.value;      
        var input_Subcatagory=document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;
      } 
      else if(section=="LEGAL")
      {
      
        document.getElementById("LEGALDiv").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("REGDiv").style.display="none";
        var subsection=document.getElementById("LEGALDiv_subcatagory");
        var sub_catagory_input=subsection.value;      
        var input_Subcatagory=document.getElementById("subcatagoryinput");
        input_Subcatagory.value=sub_catagory_input;
      } 
      }
```

```html
<div  class="departmentdiv" onclick="fields()"><!-- here the function field is called on onclick event -->
      <label>Department Name:</label> 
      <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
      <select id = "seldprt" onfocus="fields();" onchange="fields();" onkeypress="fields();">
       <option value = "LEGAL">LEGAL</option>
       <option value = "REGULATORY">REGULATORY</option>
      </select>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div id="REGDiv" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none" >
      <label>Section Name:</label>
       <div align="right" class="selectdiv">
        <select id = "REGDiv_subcatagory" onfocus="fields()" onchange="fields()" onkeyup="fields()">
         <option value = "GLT">GLT</option>
         <option value = "REGULATORY">REGULATORY</option>
        </select>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div id="LEGALDiv" class="subcatagorydiv" style="display:none" >
      <label>Section Name:</label>
       <div align="right" class="selectdiv" >
        <select id = "LEGALDiv_subcatagory" onfocus="fields()" onchange="fields()" onkeyup="fields()">
         <option value = "GLT">GLT</option>
         <option value = "LEGAL">LEGAL</option>
        </select>
       </div>
     </div>

    <form action="" method="post" >
       <div class="entry" onclick="previous_values()" style="">Name</div>
       <input type="text" style="" name="name" id="departmentinput">
       <div class="entry" style="" onclick="previous_values()">Section Number</div>
       <input type="text" style="" name="Section" id="subcatagoryinput">
       <div id="readwrite_buttons" class="hide">
        <button id="ok" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">OK</button>
        <button id="cancel" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Cancel</button>
       </div>
       <div id="readonly_buttons" class="hide">
        <button id="back" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Back</button>
       </div>
      </form>
```